# next/navigation giving error: navigator is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, navigation

The page is redirected on form submission without going to the catch block. But, in the backend, I am getting the following error: the API body is not being executed.

Here is the page code.

```js
"use client";
import { Button, TextField } from "@radix-ui/themes";
import SimpleMDE from "react-simplemde-editor";
import "easymde/dist/easymde.min.css";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

interface IssueInterface {
  title: string;
  description: string;
}

const NewIssue = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { register, control, handleSubmit } = useForm<IssueInterface>();
  return (
    <form
      className=" max-w-xl space-y-3"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(async (data) => {
        try {
          await axios.post("/issues/new", data);
          router.push("/issues");
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      })}
    >
      <TextField.Root>
        <TextField.Input placeholder="Title" {...register("title")} />
      </TextField.Root>
      <Controller
        name="description"
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <SimpleMDE placeholder="Description" {...field} />
        )}
      />
      <Button>Create Issue</Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default NewIssue;
```

The error on the terminal

> ⨯ node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js (18:0) @ eval
> ⨯ ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
> at **webpack_require** (/Users/krushanumohapatra/www/others/my_next_issue_tracker/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
> at **webpack_require** (/Users/krushanumohapatra/www/others/my_next_issue_tracker/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
> at **webpack_require** (/Users/krushanumohapatra/www/others/my_next_issue_tracker/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
> at eval (./app/issues/new/page.tsx:9:80)
> at (ssr)/./app/issues/new/page.tsx (/Users/krushanumohapatra/www/others/my_next_issue_tracker/.next/server/app/issues/new/page.js:272:1)
> at **webpack_require** (/Users/krushanumohapatra/www/others/my_next_issue_tracker/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
> at JSON.parse ()
> null

Answer (score 6):

You can fix it by replacing the existing import statement for SimpleMDE (`import SimpleMDE from "react-simplemde-editor";`) with the following code snippet:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const SimpleMDE = dynamic(() => import('react-simplemde-editor'), { ssr: false })
```

This code change utilizes Next.js's dynamic import to ensure that the react-simplemde-editor component is not included on the server side (SSR: Server Side Rendering) but only on the client side. This is important in cases where components are not compatible with server-side rendering.

Comment: Man, it took my days to find this solution. Upvoted. Works in NextJS 14.0.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

You're coming from Mosh Hemdani's course of Next.js (the practice part). I just had the same problem you mentioned and I searched for a solution, but, apparently, your problem is the only result I found. Now I'm not completely sure why this is happening, 'cause my code looks exactly like his and yours - and for him it works as it's intended and supposed to. Perhaps it's because he's using an older version of Next.js 13 - while (and I'm assuming you too) I'm using the latest. Anyway. This is the way I solved the problem:

```
<form
    className="space-y-3"
    onSubmit={handleSubmit(async (data) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("/api/issues", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            });
            if (!response.ok) throw new Error();
            router.push("/issues");
        } catch (error) {
            setError("An unexpected error occurred.");
        }
    })}
>
```

An `ok` status means different codes for different requests. For a GET, indeed, 200 is the `ok` status code, but for a DELETE, for example, 204 would be the `ok` and for a POST (which we're interested in here) 201 is the `ok` status code (created). You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200).

So I'm simply checking the status code (be it `ok` or not) after the API returns the JSON response and then, if the status is not `ok`, I'm manually throwing an Error (empty as it is) that will trigger the catch portion of the try-catch block. I'm not pretty sure how the error is being triggered in Mosh's example, though :))

L.E.: I didn't test with axios, for I chose to use `fetch`, but I guess it's the same idea.

L.L.E.: I just tested with axios and, apparently, there's no need for checking the `ok` status. It seems like axios is already throwing an error along the way if the status is not `ok`. I'll stick to `fetch`, however :P

Comment: Did axios work for you lately?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that that the problem you are experiencing is a side effect by calling a function inside a components return section. Change the following line to look like this:

```js
onSubmit={() => {
  handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    try {
      await axios.post("/issues/new", data);
      router.push("/issues");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}};
```

I guess the `navigator is not defined` error you are encountering is just the byproduct of a render loop.

Comment: I tried that, No change in the error. Tried restarting the server as per a few other documentation.

Comment: @KRUSHANUMOHAPATRA Could you please edit your answer to include the `handleSubmit` function?

Comment: Handle submit is from useForm.
const { register, control, handleSubmit } = useForm<IssueInterface>();

Comment: Ah. Well that stuff is experimental. There may still be bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly I am not seeing that error anymore. Seems like a next js version issue which got fixed with time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to error handling, wrap your submit function in a try-catch block, it should fix the error.

```
onSubmit={() => {
  handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    try {
      await axios.post("/issues/new", data);
      router.push("/issues");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}};
```